# how to make Separator line of listview more thick + xamari.forms

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

by setting SeparatorVisibility="Default" we can get separator line  between items of listview in xamarin.

but this line is very thin.

how can i increase thickness of this line to make it visible properly.

i do not want to put extra box view with desired height for separator line.i need to use default separator only

any suggestion most appreciated.

Comment: you will need to create a custom renderer to do that.